# Better solution when setting a property lazily

Tags: c#, properties

I have lots of code similar to the following, which is used to lazily load properties and avoid costly re-fetches.

I know there's been a lot of changes in recent c# versions with regard to properties, but I can't find anything that would negate the need for something like this.

Is there now a better way of handling this scenario, or is this still the way to go?

```
private string _answer;

public string Answer => _answer ?? (_answer = GetAnswer());

private string GetAnswer()
{
    var answer = "";
    return answer;
}
```

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious choice would be `Lazy<T>`:

```
private Lazy<string> _answerLazy = new Lazy<string>(() => "answer");

public string Answer => _answerLazy.Value;
```

You can leave out the method and use the lazy action instead. Also, `Lazy<T>` has options for thread safety, which I would prefer. Also, evaluating to `null` doesn't mean it keeps calculating the 'new' value.

If the advantages of `Lazy<T>` aren't enough for you to move to it, just keep using what you do. It may be cumbersome to write and more error-prone, but it will work.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer Patrick. A question about your answer "evaluating to null doesn't mean it keeps calculating the new value" - not sure what you mean by this.

Comment: Check what happens if your `GetAnswer` returns `null`. It will keep calling `GetAnswer` every time you cal l`Answer`.

Comment: One issue I've noticed is that I can't use HttpContext in my initializer method because it isn't static

Comment: I don't get what you mean.

Comment: Where you have => "answer", I sometimes use a 'Get' method, for instance GetAnswer() - which is fine if it's static, but it seems HttpContext can't be used as in GetAnswer(HttpContext context);

Comment: Then you have to assign the lazy from the constructor.